# Como colocar uma GIF animada em um APP no Android?

Tags: android, animação

Bom, estou com esse problema há algum tempo, tentei resolver utilizando respostas do StackOverflow gringo mas não obtive sucesso.

Preciso colocar uma imagem GIF animada em minha activity mas o ImageView não reproduz uma imagem .gif, ele apenas a mostra como uma imagem sem animação.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Lembrando que estou programando para Android.

Comment: A idéia do android nunca foi dar suporte ao gif, ao invés disso tente utilizar o animation e SVG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a lib Glide para isso

[image]

segue o exemplo:

no Gradle adicione

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
```

}

exemplo em sua Activity

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("https://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/gifanimation2.gif")
.into(idDoTeuImageView);
```

Caso seja da pasta drawable

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.gifanimation2) // aqui é teu gif
            .asGif()
            .into(gif);
```

Primeiro contexto de sua Class, segundo a url do Gif ou do drawable e terceiro teu ImageView que no caso é o id dele.

Link da lib https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Fiz o que disse mas o image view simplesmente não aparece nada, nem mesmo uma imagem sem animação, ele fica vazio.

Comment: No caso como você fez? pegou da pasta drawable ou de uma url? lembrando que o id do teu Image view você tem que fazer todo aquele processo de casting: ImageView meuImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewDoLayout); na lib voce vai por o meuImageView

Comment: Testei pegando da pasta drawable e depois com um URL.

Sim eu fiz o casting. Na activity ficou assim:

ImageView gif = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.animacao).into(gif);

Comment: Editei a minha resposta por favor veja. Acabei de testar e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.gifanimation2)
            .asGif()
            .into(gif);

Comment: Funcionou!! Mas o estranho é que a imagem parece ter perdido um pouco a qualidade, ela tbm se move mais lentamente que a gif original e tbm deixa um rastro por onde se mexe. Sabe dizer como arrumar ou sabe qual o motivo?

Comment: Que bom, nesse link: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en tem explicando sobre isso e como fazer para melhorar a qualidade essa lib é muito boa, ela tem um parâmetro para deixar e fazer carregamento do cache .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) ele é bom porque seu app não vai precisar mais ir na pasta drawable buscar a imagem/gif e sim do cache que é mais rápido. De uma olhada também no wiki no link da lib que deixei na resposta.

Comment: Agradeço vou ver o que consigo fazer :)

Answer (score 6):

O `android` nativamente não tem recurso para `.gif` animado.
Para você fazer este efeito teremos que ter todas as imagens da animação disponíveis para serem adicionadas em um `xml`.

Então crie um xml chamado `animation.xml` e adicione este conteúdo ao mesmo:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
id="animacao" android:oneshot="false" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android1" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android2" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android3" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android4" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android5" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android6" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/android7" android:duration="150" />
</animation-list>
```

E no xml da sua `Activity` crie um `ImageView`

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imgAndroid"
    android:background="@drawable/android1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Agora na sua classe da Activity vincule o `ImageView`  e crie um  `AnimationDrawable`  implementando sua classe desta forma:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private ImageView imgAndroid;
    private AnimationDrawable mAnimation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgAndroid = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgAndroid);
    imgAndroid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);    

    mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)imgAndroid.getBackground();
    mAnimation.start();

}

}
```

E para parar a animação use:  `mAnimation.stop();`

Comment: Nice! Melhor resposta na minha opinião!

Comment: Obrigado !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Tive problemas para implementar o gif animado no meu projeto e resolvi de uma forma bem simples:

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imgAndroid"
android:background="@drawable/android1"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Mudei para: (retirei a referência da imagem android:background="@drawable/android1")

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imgAndroid"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

A implementação é a mesma já informada:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.gift_animated).asGif().into(img_splash_animated);
```

Pode ser que ajude alguém.